# display ls pid inside ps output

Tags: linux, bash

I want to display to pid of ls inside ps output. How can I do that? 
The best I could come up with was:
`ls & ps`, but of course the ps output is:

```
[1] 26643
myfile.c 
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 3162 pts/0    00:00:01 bash
26644 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
[1]+  Done                    ls --color=auto
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `ls` hang around longer by giving it more work to do

```
$ ls -lR / > /dev/null 2>&1 & ps
[1] 21663
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
21638 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
21663 pts/0    00:00:00 ls
21664 pts/0    00:00:00 ps

$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 ls --color=tty -lR / > /dev/null 2>&1 &
$ kill %1
$
```